# Store Image in DataTable

Tags: wpf, image, datatable, icons, default

I want to store image into my datatable and while adding colum I want to set its default value, sending you code doing with checkboxes..

public void addCheckBoxesRuntime(){
for (int i = 0; i < InformationOne.Length; i++)
            {
                dt = new DataColumn(InformationOne[i][1] + " (" + InformationOne[i][0] + "                 )");

```
            dt.DataType = typeof(Boolean);

            viewDataTable.Columns.Add(dt);
            dt.DefaultValue = false;                
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `DataColumn` with type `string` and then store the string binary of the image into the field. Alternatively, use the binary itself with a `byte[]`.

Should work 100%.

Something along the lines of this:

```
public string ImageConversion(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    if (image == null) 
       return string.Empty;

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
       image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

       string value = string.Empty;

       for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt <= memoryStream.ToArray.Length - 1; intCnt++) 
       {
           value = value + memoryStream.ToArray(intCnt) + ",";
       }

       return value;
    }
}
```